# render image file with Response.OutputStream.Write

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my project, which is used to save files by binarizing them and storing the binary value in the database, the output image with the following code (in cshtml )  encounters an error in opening, but this piece of code opens Word or pdf type files.
[image]

[image]
When we open the photo, it gives an error message and does not open:
its look like we don't support this file format

```
 Response.ContentType = baharAccountancy.Models.global.fixMiMes(Model.Suffix);
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Model.Name );
Response.OutputStream.Write(Model.FileContent, 0, Model.FileContent.Length);
Response.End();
```

my model is this:

```
    {
    public long FileDBId { get; set; }
    public byte[] FileContent { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Suffix { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> Length { get; set; }
}
```